# How to develop an Android app in 32bits OS after 2020

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using window 7 32bits OS. And I wanna practice Android code. So i decided to install Android studio but it is not supporting 32 bits os in 2020 announced by the Google.
So I chose an alternative way to setup the environment with eclipse neon 3.

1. Downloaded Plug in.
   2.downloaded SDK manager.
   3.and virtual device also.

But when I have created my first app then it is showing errors.

1. Android.R file not created.
2. Error in style.xml to resolve it I decided to download appcompat support library. But Android support library not present in SDK manager.
   What can I do to resolve this problem.
   Plz suggest how to work with Android in 32bit os by using eclipse in 2020.

Comment: why dont to do this in a ununtu VM with 64 bit environment

Comment: Is it possible to having a 64 bit virtual os on 32bit system.

Comment: check the output of lscpu to know more - https://askubuntu.com/questions/564010/can-i-install-a-64-bit-version-of-ubuntu-on-my-32-bit-machine